# Permission error while trying to import module in Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a module in Python 3.X (6 and 5) and I am getting a permission error.

```
import meshio as msh

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xxxxx/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.5.5.201603221110/pysrc/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/meshio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(pipdate.check(__name__, __version__), end='')
  File "/home/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipdate/helpers.py", line 104, in check
    _log_time(name, datetime.now())
  File "/home/xxxxx/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipdate/helpers.py", line 67, in _log_time
    with open(_log_file, 'w') as handle:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/xxxxx/.cache/pipdate/log/times.log'
```

The strangest thing is that a few days ago I was able to import this module without any problem.

What can I do to solve this problem? I already searched through here, but none of the related problems match this case.

I am using Eclipse as IDE, but the same problem occurs no matter the editor I use.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the pipdate library. Have you tried to update it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this file is locked in write mode (perhaps there was a shutdown of your computer and the lock wasn't released), meaning that you can't open it. 
Since it is in your cache and it seems to be a log file, it should not be an issue to delete it (with sudo because the file is locked).

Comment: I tried to uninstall and install again, but it doesn't work. (I used pip to do so). How can I do it in sudo mode?

Comment: sudo rm -f /home/xxxxx/.cache/pipdate/log/times.log

Comment: Investigate the answer of nosklo then :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the module you're trying to use is importing `pipdate.helpers` module and that module tries to create a file **on import** (which is a very bad idea, by the way)

The user running the code doesn't have permission to create the file in the directory specified so it fails.

Comment: But I didn't install the package as a super user. I used pip to install it. It shouldn't be a problem to read/ write files, since I didn't use any super user command...

Comment: @Gabs permission system is a lot more complex than just using super user.